# Bash syntax error when variable exceeds 1000000

Tags: bash, awk

I have a fairy simple script.

Here is a file:

```
>cat log1.txt
2021-07-29 16:58:47;MA;sell;1700.52;USD;606;65fae90c-7943-11eb-9726-8c85906a186d
```

Here is my script (it is supposed to multiply the value in the fourth column by the value in the sixth column):

```
File=`cat log1.txt`
profit+=`echo "$File" | awk -F\; '{ num1=$4+0;num2=$6+0;if($3 == "sell") { temp+=num1*num2 }else{temp-=num1*num2} } END {print temp}' | bc`
```

I came across some very unexpected behavior. As soon as the total profit exceeds 1 million, my script returns a syntax error. If the profit is below 1 million, it works.

Example of an input file that works

```
2021-07-29 16:58:47;MA;sell;1600.52;USD;606;65fae90c-7943-11eb-9726-8c85906a186d
```

Why is that? I've been pulling my hair out for hours now.

Comment: Do you know what the output of the awk command is?

Comment: We'd rather have an example that fails...

Comment: You're missing the most important piece of information, what is the error?  Also what is `bc` doing there?

Comment: Where in the script is `temp` initialized?

Comment: @ampersander: It should be a number, but it's in fact `1.03052e+06` which `bc` doesn't understand.

Comment: Does this give a hint `echo 3.51575e+06 | bc
(standard_in) 1: parse error`  (I made up some numbers >1000000 :-)

Comment: Thank you, @choroba, that was indeed the problem. Wanna post your comment as an answer so that I may flag is as a correct one?

Comment: You can modify your awk to work - use printf - see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html - `printf ("%d\n", temp);` gives 3515745 compared with earlier value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the `awk` command with the particular input is `1.03052e+06`, but `bc` doesn't understand this format. Instead of printing the value, use `printf` in `awk`:

```
awk -F\; '{ num1=$4+0;num2=$6+0;if($3 == "sell") { temp+=num1*num2 }else{temp-=num1*num2} } END {printf "%d\n",temp}'
```